# Compiling a Header file into a DLL

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, header

I have created a function library that I want to create a DLL from and create an export library. Creating the DLL is not the problem.

The problem is that, I do not want the developer/user to look inside the header file as the code is not optimized and some of it looks a mess even though it works.

Is there anyway I can include the contents of the header file within another DLL so that the header file will then be hidden or is there a way to compile the header to Binary?

Win32, visual studio 2010, 'c/c++'.

Comment: How about moving your hideous implementation out of the header file and into your DLL.

Comment: I agree with WhozCraig. The header file defines the functions that a C/C++ app is allowed to make in the DLL. So you have to give the developers the header file.  If there is something in there you do not want them to see, and it does not affect their ability to use the DLL, then take it out of the header file, it likely did not belong there in the first place.

Comment: Er, the DLL is the binary that you compiled your source to

Comment: Clean and readable headers are your friend. Often they are your only friend when the documentation sucks. Please don't take this last line of assistance from us other poor writers of software. We can write better code when we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the code from the header:  just declare the functions and specify the classes (i.e. no code in there):

```
//header 
void my_ignomous_function(int);
class my_ignomous_class {
public: 
     my_ignomous_class();
     ~my_ignomous_class();
     bool my_ignomous_member(my_ignomous_class &x); 
private: 
     // unfortunately, you have to give these details.  
};
```

If this is not sufficient, you could use the [pimpl idiom](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/):  in your class you use a pointer to an object that is used for the implementation.  The advantage is that you can just declare the implementation class without any details in the header. The details are only needed in the implementation.

```
//header 
class my_nice_class {
public: 
     my_nice_class()
     ~my_nice_class()
     bool my_nice_member(my_nice_class &x); 
private: 
     class my_horrible_secret_class *impl; 
};
```

The other approach is to fune-tune your design, so that you've no longer anything to hide ;-)

Comment: Extra props if I could vote twice for demonstrating the pImpl, but I'd pop the pimpl (snerk) into a unique_ptr for that extra warm and fuzzy feeling you get from Rule of three compliance.

Comment: I'd recommend against exporting C++ implementations from a DLL. It's difficult enough to comply with the restrictions imposed by the CRT (see [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx)). Adding invisible code paths (e.g. by passing freestore-backed container references, or throwing exception objects) won't improve the situation.

Comment: I disagree with your comment // unfortunately, you have to give these details. 
//forward declaration above class my_nice_class
class MyNicePrivateMembers;


private:
  MyNiceMembers* members;


// inside cpp

class MyNiceMembers {
friend class my_nice_class;
private:
  bool really;
  std::string whyNot;

Comment: @relascope please read my answer to its end, because I proposed 2 levels of solution, depending on what needs to be hidden : 1) the first block of code is basic header cleaning technique, and my comment applies to this cleaning technique only; 2) the second block of code uses an opaque pointer exactly like your proposal (I just didn’t show its obvious forward declaration, considering that  Herb Sutter’s linked article provided all the details and explanations.

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned you have to separate Declaration and Definition [1]

Declaration in Header (.h), export only functions the developers need [2] - no need for a .def file.
The user has to know the Declarations of the functions he is using. So he needs the header.

Definition (function body - implementation) in Source file (.cpp)

Maybe you can split it up into more header/source - pairs so that the header for the Developers solely contains the clean "interface" of your library - the exported function.

https://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-declspec-dllexport?view=msvc-170